# When to use Property Delegation in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I saw this great talk by Lisa Wray sometime back https://youtu.be/0cjr4K0tqs4?t=493 which inspired me to create different Property delegates for all my ViewBindings like `BindActivity(layoutId)`, `BindFragment`, `BindViewGroup`, etc.
My colleague had created extension functions for the same like `Activity.bind(layoutId)`, `View.bind()`, `ViewGroup.bind()`, etc. which made me wonder which should be preferred over here. I tried decompiling the kotlin byte code and it :

1. Property Delegation would create a new object like `private final BindActivity binding$delegate = new BindActivity(2131361819);`
2. It seems to be using Reflection, something like the following to initialize `KProperty` :

   `static final KProperty[] $$delegatedProperties = new KProperty[]{(KProperty)Reflection.property1(new PropertyReference1Impl(Reflection.getOrCreateKotlinClass(MainActivity.class), "binding", "getBinding()Lcom/abcd/package/databinding/ActivityMainBinding;")), … another lazy delegated property};`

`(ActivityMainBinding)this.binding$delegate.getValue((Activity)this, $$delegatedProperties[0])`

Question 1: If property delegation uses reflection, what is the use-case to use them?

Questions 2: Also, kotlin’s `Reflection` class seems to be using some reflection factory `kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactoryImpl` so does it mean that the reflection could be not as slow in kotlin as in java?

Comment: Most property delegates do not use reflection. `KProperty` is just a plain object used to provide information about the delegated property such as its name.

Comment: This question could help: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8b7aaf/eli5_delegation_in_kotlin/

Comment: Be careful not to mix _reflective member lookup_ (slow) with _reflective member access_ (very fast).