# When should I use delegation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, delegates

I have been going through multiple links ([One](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8b7aaf/eli5_delegation_in_kotlin/), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708419/when-to-use-property-delegation-in-kotlin)) and [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) regarding the delegate pattern and somewhat understand the advantage it brings in the form of "*composition over inheritance*". I can see how the inbuilt delegate properties (lazy, vetoable, map, observable) are useful; but having a hard time understanding 2 areas:

**1. Why/When should I write a custom delegate for property? How is it better than overriding getter/setter of that property?**

Comparing the 2 approaches:

```
private var withoutDelegate: String = ""
    get() = DataHelper.getLatestData(::withoutDelegate.name)
    set(value) {
        DataHelper.setLatestData(value)
        field = value
    }

val withDelegate by StringDelegateProvider()

class StringDelegateProvider {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: String?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        return DataHelper.getLatestData(property.name)
    }
}
```

**2. At the class level, how is delegation better than traditional composition patterns?**

Comparing the 2 approaches - composition without delegation seems much more concise:

```
interface Base {
    fun print()
}

class BaseImpl1(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun print() { print(x) }
}

class BaseImpl2(val x: Int) : Base {
    override fun print() { print(x) }
}

class Derived(b: Base) : Base by b

fun clientFunctionWithDelegation() {
    val i1 = BaseImpl1(10)
    val i2 = BaseImpl2(10)

    val b1 = Derived(i1)
    val b2 = Derived(i2)

    b1.print()
    b2.print()
}

fun clientFunctionWithoutDelegation(){
    //wihtout extending Base, we can still create multiple types of Base and use them conditionally.
    val i1: Base = BaseImpl1(10)
    val i2: Base = BaseImpl2(10)

    i1.print()
    i2.print()
}
```

Would appreciate if the community can share some use-cases where delegation can help.

Comment: 1: You can reuse the delegate without having to override `get` and `set` each time.   Example: the `lazy` delegate

Comment: 2: let's say you want to create a `MutableList` that prints the list every time you mutate the list. You don't want to reimplement `MutableList`, you just want to override the functions mutating the list. So instead of manually delegating *every* call, you just say `class PrintList<T>(original: MutableList<T>) by original` and you *just* override the functions you care about

Comment: @gpunto Can you please post these comments as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: You can reuse the delegate without having to override `get` and/or `set` each time. Example: the `lazy` delegate

2: let's say you want to create a `MutableList` that prints the list every time you mutate the list. You don't want to reimplement `MutableList`, you just want to override the functions mutating the list. So instead of manually delegating every call, you just say `class PrintList<T>(original: MutableList<T>) by original` and you just override the functions you care about